# Pan and Zoom (on mouse-wheel) based on cursor location

Tags: javascript, zooming, pan

The purpose of my code is to be able to pan and zoom a div element. It works perfectly fine except that the zooming is done from the center (which is normal). I need the div to zoom based on the cursor location (kind of like google maps zoom works) so I used transform-origin to shift the zoom from the center to the cursor's location. It works totally fine, except that whenever I change the mouse position to zoom again, the div element 'jumps' a few pixels and after this 'jump' it works (zoom and panning) perfectly fine again.

I think the reason is that I am not calculating the new distances correctly (after zooming) since the origin of the div changes.

Anyone can help on this one please?

NB: If I zoom out then zoom in to the exact same scale, there will be no 'jump'.

You can have a look at my code here in case I wasn't clear enough:

```js
window.onload = function () {
    initializeImage();
};


function initializeImage() {

    var recElements = document.getElementsByClassName("rec");
    var rec = recElements[0];
    rec.panning = {};
    rec.imageZoom = 100;

    rec.stoprecMove = function () {
        this.panning.xMouseDown = null;
        this.panning.yMouseDownn = null;
    };

    rec.recMove = function() {
        var dx = 0;
        var dy = 0;
        var scale = this.imageZoom * 0.01;
        var pos = this.getBoundingClientRect();
        dx = (this.panning.xMove - this.panning.xMouseDown) / scale;
        dy = (this.panning.yMove - this.panning.yMouseDown) / scale;        
        dx = startOffsetX + dx;
        dy = startOffsetY + dy;

        var xZoom = this.xZoom;
        var yZoom = this.yZoom;
        var xTransform = xZoom - dx;
        var yTransform = yZoom - dy;
        
        var dxInPixel = dx + "px";
        var dyInPixel = dy + "px";

        this.style.transform = "translate(" + dxInPixel + "," + dyInPixel + ")" + "scale(" + scale + ")";
        this.style.transformOrigin = xTransform + "px" + " " + yTransform + "px";

        this.lastX = dx;
        this.lastY = dy;

    };

    rec.onmousewheel = function (e) {
        this.panning.xMove = 0;
        this.panning.yMove = 0;
        this.panning.xMouseDown = 0;
        this.panning.yMouseDown = 0;
        this.xZoom = e.clientX;
        this.yZoom = e.clientY;
        if (typeof this.lastX === "undefined") {
           startOffsetX = 0;
           startOffsetY = 0;
        }
        else {
           startOffsetX = this.lastX;
           startOffsetY = this.lastY;
        }
        var zoom = rec.imageZoom;
        var delta = event.detail ? event.detail * -120 : event.wheelDelta;
        zoom += delta / 15;
        if (zoom > 300) zoom = 300; else if (zoom < 30) zoom = 30;
        rec.imageZoom = zoom;

        this.recMove();
    };

    rec.onmousedown = function (e) {
        var xMouseDown = e.clientX;
        var yMouseDown = e.clientY;
        console.log("x: " + xMouseDown + " y: " + yMouseDown);
        this.panning.xMouseDown = xMouseDown;
        this.panning.yMouseDown = yMouseDown;
        if (typeof this.lastX === "undefined") {
            startOffsetX = 0;
            startOffsetY = 0;
        }
        else {
            startOffsetX = this.lastX;
            startOffsetY = this.lastY;
        }
        e.preventDefault();
    };

    rec.onmousemove = function (e) {
        if (this.panning.xMouseDown && this.panning.yMouseDown) {
            this.panning.xMove = e.clientX;
            this.panning.yMove = e.clientY;
            this.recMove();

            e.preventDefault();
        }

    };

    rec.onmouseup = function () {
        this.stoprecMove();
    };

    rec.onmouseout = function () {
        this.stoprecMove();
    };


}
```

```css
.rec {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(to right, yellow, gray 10%, green 15%, yellow 30%, gray 40%, green 45%, yellow 60%, gray 70%, green 75%, yellow 90%, gray 100%);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div class = "rec"></div>
</body>
</html>
```